# Ошибка в коде: ReferenceError: getElement is not defined

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня ошибка в коде, подскажите что не так с переменной ?

```
function setImage(elementId, strImage) {
    var imageElem = getElement(elementId);
    if (!imageElem) return;
    imageElem.src = strImage;
}

function iSwap(imgID, newImg) {
    newImgPath = "" + newImg;
    setImage(imgID, newImgPath);
}
```

Консоль ошибок ругается на это: ReferenceError: getElement is not defined. Ошибка непосредственно в строке:

```
var imageElem = getElement( elementId );
```

Comment: видимо функция `getElement` не определена

Comment: А я думаю что не определен elementId, но как правильно не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `getElement` не определена, строго говоря он даже не знает что это функция. Соответственно, либо надо её где-то описать, либо использовать методы из `document` - `document.getElementById()`, `document.getElementsByTagName()` и `document.getElementsByName()`.
Как использовать можно прочитать [тут](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom/search).